# what is the easiest way to build forms to import to db

Tags: python, sqldb

I need to convert an excel sheet that is shared between couple of users and they do insert/update on it to a more DB/web-based application. What would be the easiest route to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, What you want achieve is to switch from Excel file to web/based application.

1. you have to create a SQL (Postgresql, Mysql...) database that represent the data structure of the excel file.
2. Create REST API for web application
3. Create your web interfaces in order to perform input data using html, css and javascript.

To achieve this, in python you have a lot of web frameworks that simplify your work. following some of the most popular:

- Django https://www.djangoproject.com/start/
- Flask https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/
- Pyramid https://trypyramid.com/

Or maybe take a look of this tool, Streamlit https://streamlit.io/